# SharePoint 2010 Document List

Tags: document-library, alert

Good morning.

I have a set of requirements for some simple document storage and I am investigating the possibility of using an existing SharePoint 2010 system.

We need:

- A location where multiple documents will be submitted on a weekly
  basis.
- All previous weeks documents must be maintained for traceability.
- An alert/notification/email should be generated at the end of each
  week which indicates any documents which have not been submitted.
- It should be possible to add comments to each of the submitted
  documents.

My main question is if this would be possible within SharePoint 2010 without the use of customised webparts?  If so how would I approach implementing this and what should I be reading up on?

Any suggestions or pointers to relevant information or starting advice would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your requirements are met by a Sharepoint 2010 Document Library.
Just add a column for the comments to the document library.
Maybe you will find this [Introduction to Document Libraries in SharePoint 2010](https://richardihogan.wordpress.com/2011/01/18/introduction-to-document-libraries-in-sharepoint-2010-part-1/) helpful.